# Static Smart Pointers - Yay or Nay?

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I have an object-- we'll called it Obj-- and I want it contain a static pointer to an instance of it's own type. Ex:

```
class Obj{
    static auto get_active_obj() -> const Obj*;
    auto make_active_obj() -> void;

private:
    static const Obj* active;
};
```

Now, would it be good practice to use a smart pointer, specifically a shared_ptr, in this scenario? The idea behind using a shared_ptr here is that when the user queries the object with get_active_obj, I can just return a weak_ptr to the active object, and the user could query this to check if the active object has changed/is still valid. Now, question is, is this the most optimal (or even a viable) solution? Ex:

```
class Obj{
    static auto get_active_obj() -> std::weak_ptr<const Obj>;
    auto make_active_obj() -> void;

private:
    //another concern with this is that I have to provide a "no-OP" 
    //deleter to prevent a segfault when the shared_ptr tries to delete a static    
    //pointer.
    static std::shared_ptr<const Obj> active;
};

int main(){
    Obj o;
    o.make_active_obj();

    auto active = Obj::get_active_obj();
    if(active.expired()){ //is it still active?
        auto active_obj = active.lock();
        //do stuff
    }

}
```

Conceptual implementation of make_active_obj():

```
auto make_active_obj()const -> void {
    active.reset(this);
}
```

destructor:

```
~Obj(){
    if(this == active.get())
        active.reset();
}
```

Comment: If you return a weak pointer, there could be a race where the object is destroyed before it is locked

Comment: @nish: how could that be resolved? just call lock() and test if it's a nullptr?

Comment: Return a shared pointer instead?

Comment: If the caller wants to store a weak reference, s/he has the option of doing that.

Comment: Don't return a shared ptr, but instead of checking for expired and then locking the ptr, do it the other way round: first lock the weak_ptr and then check whether you got a valid (non-empty)

Comment: What is the active object by the way / for what is it used?

Comment: @mikemb: it's being used as a window class, and the active object is the active window. (btw, one of you guys post as an answer and I'll accept it)

Comment: @mikemb whats the advantage of returning a weak pointer?

Comment: Sorry, but think I have to retract my statement. If you intend to use the active object directly after retrieving the pointer, then there is of course no use in using a weak_ptr

Comment: @nishantjr I just didn't think this through. I thought Shokwav wanted to pass a weak_ptr for some reason and I though about how to make this work wihtout a race condition instead of thinking whether it makes sense at all - sorry for the confusion

Comment: NP, I've used this pattern recently in a project, and returned a weak pointer. Besides the race, I realized that in every case I used it, I locked immediately.

Comment: excellent, thanks guys. again, one of you post an answer and i'll accept. one more thing: will this create an issue when the static shared_ptr finally gets destructed?

Comment: I don't think it is a problem, but you need to implement some kind of `reset` or `make_inactive` function that resets the static pointer to a nullpointer. Otherwise your active window will only be destroyed after main returns which is probably supposed to happen after all windows have been destroyed.

Comment: Once `make_active_obj()` has been called, what would make the object expire?

Comment: @prae: another call to make_active_obj. the objects are free to be destroyed on their own, the static pointer simply holds a pointer to a window.

Comment: Are you aware that, as soon as you reassign the last `shared_ptr` that is pointing to an object, this object is destroyed? Also you must never call `delete` on an object that is managed by a `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would reverse the use of shared and weak_ptr in your program. That is: I would use a static `weak_ptr` to hold a reference to the current active object, but return a `shared_ptr` whenever someones calling `get_active_obj()` in order to work with it.

```
class Obj{
    static std::shared_ptr get_active_obj();
    void make_active_obj();

private:
    static std::weak_ptr<const Obj> active;
};

int main(){
    Obj o;
    o.make_active_obj();

    auto active = Obj::get_active_obj();
    if(active){ //is it still active?
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

The reason is that you probably want to be able to destroy/close your active object without having to make another object active before (e.g. before terminating your program).
This would also better fit the semantics of your program: When some function wants to work with the active object it has to be sure that the object won't be destroyed while working on it, so this is a (temporary) owning relationship. The class on the other hand probably doesn't care if a object is destroyed or not, as it only provides a reference to other parts of the program, so this is a non-owning relationship.

Comment: the critical flaw with this design is that weak_ptr<> can't be reassigned a different (raw) pointer :/

Comment: @Shokwav: Why not? Correct me if I'm wrong, but you can always create a `shared_ptr` from a raw pointer and then assign that to the `weak_ptr`. But, whats more important: Using `shared_ptr` or `weak_ptr` in general ist only sensible, if the object is managed ONLY by smartpointers (which - in addition - are copies of each other) in the first place, so it should not be necessary to assign a raw pointer to `active`, because as long as the object is alive there should be a `shared_ptr` pointing to it. If this is not the case, your design in the question will most probably fail too.

Comment: Or did I missunderstand something?

Comment: i have a few instances of Window objects. a user can make one "active" by calling the make_active() function, which assigns the (raw) Window pointer to the static smart pointer. i have updated my original post with an example to clear up any ambiguities.

Comment: @Shokwav: That should not work, because as soon as a new pointer is assigend to the smartpointer (a new window is made active) the shared_ptr will destroy the previous window. I recommend you do some additional reading about smart pointers, but in short: a shared pointer is not a mechanism to ensure a object stays alive but a mechanism to automatically destroy an object and for them to work properly you have to follow certain rules which you apparently don't follow in your code.

Comment: For me, I just wanted a static field which will be created once and reused for the duration of the program. However, a `weak_ptr` cannot exist without a `shared_ptr`, which means that if I make the static field a `weak_ptr`, it has to also have another static field containing the original `shared_ptr`, which defeats the purpose of making it static in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

After some code calls `get_active_obj()` should it then delete the active object?  As it appears that your object is on the stack, the answer is clearly no.  As such, `get_active_obj()` should DEFINITELY NOT return a owning pointer.  I would go with this:

```
class Obj{
    static const Obj* get_active_obj() {return active;}
    void make_active_obj() const {active = this;}

    ~Obj() {if (active==this) active=nullptr;}    
private:
    static const Obj* active;
};
```

Since the recipients of `get_active_obj()` aren't owning the `Obj`, all they need is a pointer.  (It would be a reference, but you can't have a nullable-reference, so pointer it is.  Also note that when the destructor of `Obj` is called, it makes itself no longer the active pointer.  Pretty simple.

Of course, this answer is 100% based on the fact your `Obj` is on the stack or managed otherwise.  If you want `make_active_obj` to share in the ownership, then see the other answer.